# Which version of gast for TF 1.15.? (Autograph warning)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, version

I am reproducing this tutorial with Google Colab:
[predict CLV with Deep Neural Networks](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/clv-prediction-with-offline-training-train?hl=de#cleaning_the_data)

It is a bit older and uses Tensorflow version: 1.10

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
```

intalled the version: 1.15.2.

Now in my Input I have several times the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function parse_csv at 0x7fd13d09b4d0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 3, expecting 4
```

and this one:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <bound method _DNNModel.call of <tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn._DNNModel object at 0x7fd1381ca2d0>> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
```

My output looks like this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Training with estimator made no steps. Perhaps input is empty or misspecified.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: None.
({'average_loss': 0.0,
  'global_step': 0,
  'label/mean': 0.0,
  'loss': 0.0,
  'prediction/mean': 0.0,
  'rmse': 0.0},
 [])
```

I found in the web some similar questions about TF 2.x versions and the answer was to use an other version of gast:

- Which version do I need for TF 1.15.2?
- How can I downgrade the current version?

In case that isn`t the issue, what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

For `Tensorflow 1.15.2`, gast version required is `0.2.2`.

Regarding warnings, These Autograph warnings can be turn off by using below code

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the latest version of GAST does not result in warnings. I'm less sure if still works correctly...

```
pip freeze | grep -i ...

gast==0.5.3
tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```